# iOS/iPhone - passing custom object between views. Object returns always null

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

I'm trying to pass a custom class between views. I have set a property for that class but when i access the property, the attributes return always null:

**firstview.m:**

```
- (void)initNextEventView{
NSDate *eventDate = [eventDatePicker date];
NSString *eventName = eventNameTextfield.text;

LocateEventViewController *locView = [[LocateEventViewController alloc]init];
locView.eventDTO.name = eventName;
locView.eventDTO.date = eventDate;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:locView animated:YES];
}
```

**LocateEventVC.h (2. view):**

```
@interface LocateEventViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, BSForwardGeocoderDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageBackground;
@property (strong, nonatomic) EventDTO *eventDTO;
```

so when i log a attribute of **eventDTO** it returns null..

any help would be great

**EDIT 1 (2. view):**
Thats how I log:

```
NSLog(@"name on 2. view: %@", eventDTO.name);
self.eventDTO.place = tmpEventPlace;
// init friends view!

//passing to next view
EventMembersViewController *members = [[EventMembersViewController alloc]init];

members.eventDTO = self.eventDTO;
```

**EventDTO.h**

```
@interface EventDTO : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UserDTO * creatorIsAppUser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ContactDTO * creatorIsNotAppUser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger *eventID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomPlacemark * place;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *invitedMembers;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *acceptedMembers;


- (NSNumber*)getLatidude;
- (NSNumber*)getLongitude;
```

**EventDTO.m**

```
@synthesize place, date, eventID, name, acceptedMembers, description, invitedMembers;


- (NSNumber*)getLatidude{
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:place.coordinate.latitude];
}

- (NSNumber*)getLongitude{
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:place.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LocateEventViewController *locView = [[LocateEventViewController alloc]init];
locView.eventDTO.name = eventName;
locView.eventDTO.date = eventDate;
```

When you initiating `locView`, the object eventDTO doesn't exists. You have to initiate a new eventDTO right there, e.g.:

```
LocateEventViewController *locView = [[LocateEventViewController alloc]init];
YourClass *eventDTO = [[YourClass alloc] init];
locView.eventDTO = eventDTO;
locView.eventDTO.name = eventName;
locView.eventDTO.date = eventDate;
```

or directly in the `-init`method of your `LocateEventViewController` by adding

```
-(id)init {
...
self.eventDTO = [[YourClassHere alloc] init];
...
}
```

Comment: thanks.. that did it... ty. but i want to know why ? why i dont need init a NSSTring for example?

Comment: You can init a string by multiple ways. One of these is to do something like the following: `NSString *myString = @"Hello, World!";`. I assume you did something like `SomeViewConroller.someString = @"Hello, Universe";`. So by adding a @-String to a property, it is initialized at the same time. That was a very short asnwer, but i should be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post for a full explanation. In short, you're going about it wrong:

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: i did the same ... it is working with a string property.. but not with that class.. This Class is a subclass of NsManagedObject. is that maybe the problem?

Comment: Could be. You would have to post all the code in order to tell for sure. The data contained in that link should get you going in the right direction though.

Comment: We have to see all the code in order to figure it out. What about EventDTO.h and .m?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the property `eventDTO` is set or allocated before accessing `eventName` and `eventDate`?

My guess is that `eventDTO` itself is nil. Calling method or accessing properties on `nil` objects is allowed in Objective-C. It does not crash as it would do in C++ or Java, it simply does nothing and returns `nil` if ht method has a return value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the property `eventDTO` is not properly initialized and it is `nil` itself.

Sending message to `nil` is legal in Objective-C, it simply fails silently and returns `nil`. It's a common pitfall when learning Objetive-C. And accessing property is just a syntactic sugar of sending messages.

BTW, "empty object" in Objective-C is represented by `nil`, not `null`, `NULL` or `NO`, although they are all zero.

Comment: Add a line like `self.eventDTO = [[EventDTO alloc] init];` in `-init` method of `LocateEventViewController`.